# Standard Borel Space

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

This is a Lemma from Tao's note: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/275a-notes-2-product-measures-and-independence/comment-page-2/#comment-681889 used to generate standard Borel spaces (a measurable space ${(\Omega,{\mathcal F})}$ is standard Borel if it is isomorphic as a measurable space to a Borel subset of the unit interval ${[0,1]}$ with Borel measure).

**Lemma 12** Let ${(X,d)}$ be a complete separable metric space, and let ${\Omega}$ be a Borel subset of ${X}$. Then ${\Omega}$ (with the Borel ${\sigma}$-algebra) is standard Borel.

Proof: Let us call two topological spaces Borel isomorphic if their corresponding Borel structures are isomorphic as measurable spaces. Using the binary expansion, we see that ${[0,1]}$ is Borel isomorphic to ${\{0,1\}^{\bf N}}$ (the countable number of points that have two binary expansions can be easily permuted to obtain a genuine isomorphism). Similarly ${[0,1]^{\bf N}}$ is Borel isomorphic to ${\{0,1\}^{{\bf N} \times {\bf N}}}$. Since ${{\bf N} \times {\bf N}}$ is in bijection with ${{\bf N}}$, we conclude that ${[0,1]^{\bf N}}$ is Borel isomorphic to ${[0,1]}$. Thus it will suffice to to show that every complete separable metric space ${(X,d)}$ is Borel isomorphic to a Borel subset of ${[0,1]^{\bf N}}$. But if we let ${q_1,q_2,\dots}$ be a countable dense subset in ${X}$, the map

$\displaystyle  x \mapsto (\frac{d(x,q_i)}{1+d(x,q_i)})_{i \in {\bf N}}$

can easily be seen to be a Borel isomorphism between ${X}$ and a Borel subset of ${[0,1]^{\bf N}}$ (note the image is the closure of the points ${(\frac{d(q_j,q_i)}{1+d(q_j,q_i)})_{i \in {\bf N}}}$ in the uniform norm). The claim follows.

**Question**: How do we rigorously justify the fact that the two maps mentioned in the proof are indeed both bijective and measurable?